# Simple if else structure. With different lang attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I make a simple if and else structure. But it is not working.
I get the error. EN is nog defined.

How can i fix that?

Thanks,

```
var theLanguage = $('html').attr('lang');
// Diferent language
if ($(theLanguage) == "en") {

} else {

}
```

Comment: This code won't work but will neither throw that error. Are you sure the error is here?

Comment: This is the error. ReferenceError: en is not defined

Comment: There is no `en` variabele here, that's why I'm wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var theLanguage = $('html').attr("lang");
```

theLanguage variable is a string literal value .

$(theLanguage) is not a jquery object that's why it throws error.

you can check as

```
if(theLanguage == ""en){
}
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the value stored in `theLanguage` to the jQuery function. Why? This will return a jQuery object, so it will never `== "en"`.

If you want to see if `"en"` is the value, you'd do a direct comparison.

```
if (theLanguage == "en") {
```

If you are getting a *ReferenceError: en is not defined*, then your `en` is missing the quotation marks `"en"`.

Answer (score 0):

`theLanguage` is the string value of the `lang` property that you presumably want to compare to `"en"` so you don't do `$(theLanguage)`, you just compare to `theLanguage` directly like this:

```
var theLanguage = $('html').attr('lang');
// Diferent language
if (theLanguage == "en") {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.attr()` function already returns a string. Don't wrap it in yet another `$()` but comrae the value directly:

```
var theLanguage = $('html').attr('lang');
// Diferent language
if (theLanguage == "en") {

} else {

}
```